# Replica is significantly behind Source on MySQL 8.x

Tags: mysql, replication

I am running a MySQL 8 source/replica setup on two dedicated bare mettal AMD servers, each on Ubuntu 20.04. Connection is fast over 1GB ethernet switch on dedicated NICs. The database replicated has over 600 million datasets, growing with about 3m per day.

It looks like replication is working, but is significantly behind master (over 1 day) according to stats:

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.0.2
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000611
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 992826392
               Relay_Log_File: dog-relay-bin.001810
                Relay_Log_Pos: 152491303
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000603
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: MyDB
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 152491088
              Relay_Log_Space: 8633174820
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 117385
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: d5e08cf9-b0e8-11eb-ae0f-fc3497662fd0
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: waiting for handler commit
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Several hours later the output looks like this:

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.0.2
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000615
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 519556177
               Relay_Log_File: dog-relay-bin.001819
                Relay_Log_Pos: 650853461
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000606
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: MyDB
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 650853246
              Relay_Log_Space: 9254356801
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 97821
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: d5e08cf9-b0e8-11eb-ae0f-fc3497662fd0
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: waiting for handler commit
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

The replica seems to be working but lags. Currently at logfile 000620:
[image]

I am using row based replication.

Apart of the delay in seconds I can not see any malfunctional warnings. What could be the problem here?

Comment: It looks like replication is working, but perhaps it can't apply changes on the replica as quickly as they are being made on the source, so it falls behind. If you run this command several times, do you see `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` keep advancing? One common problem is using row-based replication with large tables that have no primary key. So every row replicated results in a table-scan.

Comment: Yes the pos is advancing, I added a second output to the question. There are tables with well above 100m rows. In fact they have no primary key but a unique index over 4 rows, as a primary is not needed (at least I believe so).There are also foreign keys set to other tables.

Comment: @merlin - A `PRIMARY KEY` is needed on every table.  If that `UNIQUE` index has no `NULLable` columns, it has already been promoted to be the PK.  If not, then it may be the problem.

Comment: Gather more data for us to analyze.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis -- both to see slow queries (which would spot that missing PK) and to see the settings.  And provide the data for both the Primary and the Replica.

Comment: Your second output shows 97k seconds behind master, whereas the first one is 117k. So it is actually catching up, at least at this time of day. Maybe during peak times it loses ground again. You might simply have servers that are too slow to keep pace with your traffic.

Comment: @RickJames Replica was running on sys load over 10, stoped mysql, enabled slow query log, started mysql. Now at sys load 2 but seconds behind master keeps increasing while there is 0 load on source and on replica today. The slow query log is empty so far. The bin-log files are about 1G

Comment: After about 4 hours the only slow queries inside the slow query log are count() tables I ran manually. The inserts are advancing slowly. One table has 380M rows and the source has 379M, adding about 50K per hour. Today there is not traffic on the system, but every other day has about 3.5M added. Any idea how to identify the bottle neck besides the slow query log @RickJames?

Comment: Make sure that `long_query_time` is set significantly lower than the default of `10` (seconds) -- Suggest `1`.  If that is not sufficient, try `0.1`.  Also, note that running connections won't notice the change, so it may require a restart.

Comment: 500MB / hour is a lot of binlog.  Are you doing big Updates or Deletes -- that is updating or deleting millions of rows at once?

Comment: I have set it now to 0.1, slow queries are logged OK but none of them is from bin_log. Is there anything extra that needs to be activated? There are almonst only inserts. About 3.5M per day, some deletes. Edits (maybe triggereed through foreign keys unknowingly?) One table with 1M rows gets updated quite a lot though in the 100K range.